# What is SAM Account\F as reported by chntpw?

Tags: windows

I am working through some study material and decided to explore the chntpw tool.  I have a listing for SAM Account\F and it is off (0).  I am wondering what this is as I am curious why it is off and more importantly if I should learn why to turn it on.

Steps to get there:

- chntpw -i /Windows/System32/config/SAM
- Option 2

This is fresh (or to my memory fresh) VM using Windows 7.  I would likely not create a user called Account/F and it is not listed under the Usernames of any of the tools I am using.

Comment: do you mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier#Machine_SIDs

Comment: do you mean you see this: `SAM      Account\F             : 0 -> off`

Comment: Please include the output of the tool or else we are guessing at the problem and your interpretation of the output may be incorrect. From what you've supplied, it's NOT an account, but part of the SYSKEY check, and Account\F is the machine SID key in the registry.